# Express JS POST Request Failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, post

I am trying to write code to create a mongodb entry using express.js. However, when I test my code with a cURL request, I get the error "empty response from server".

Here is my express.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var util = require('util');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_db');

var channelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  verified: String,
  private: String,
  channelID: String,
  handle: String,
  subscribers: String
});

var Channel = mongoose.model("Channel", channelSchema);
router.post('/createChannel', bodyParser, function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.body) return res.send(400);
    var objID = new ObjectID();

    var newChannel = new Channel({
      name: req.body["name"],
      verified: req.body["verified"],
      private: req.body["private"],
      channelID: objID,
      handle: req.body["handle"],
      subscribers: req.body["subscribers"]
     });

    newChannel.save(function(err, point){
      if(err) res.send(500);
      else res.send(200);
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

I do not understand why the request is failing...it always times out. Does it have something to do with the HTTP response that I am giving?

Comment: Why are you defining the middleware twice? You have `router.use(bodyParser.json());` and then you are also passing `bodyParser` on the request.

Comment: how you tested? what is your cURL?

Comment: It's not failing, it just says "empty response". which is correct, because you send a response, but it's empty. Send your point back : `res.status(200).send(point)`

Comment: @Jeremy Thille Thank you. I used of your suggestion, and now I am receiving a response and the data is being appended to my database. If either of you want to place it as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not failing, it just says "empty response". Which is correct, because you send a response, but it's empty. Send your point back : `res.status(200).send(point)` or even better, `res.status(200).json(point)`.